# Tracking patent history

Tags: ownership

Is there a way to track the history of this patent? It was my Great Grandfather's and we never knew he held a patent.  I'm interested in learning more, such as whether he ever sold the patent/technology to a company or another person.

Comment: Welcome to ask patents -- this site is dedicated to the process and the prior art for granting patents and you question does not fall withoin thos parameters.  However helpful as we are, we can only help if there is a reference to the material you question -- a patent number, name of inventor or year and title of invention -- but there is no such in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the PTO website and do a search, or do a more user friendly search via google at: google.com/patents .  Just search your great grandfather's name and if he does have a patent in his name, it should pop up.  Assuming it's quite old, the patent text may be distorted if google tried to read the text which was on paper at the time.  In that case, google should also link to the source documents at the PTO in which you can then see the original document scans.

Good luck!